# How can I display the data in the right table by using javascript for-loop and if-satement?

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, if-statement, django-templates

I have some data fetching by ajax, I need to use for-loop and if-statement to check which good belongs to whose shopping cart. And then display in their table.
The for-loop and if-statement I write worked correctly in HTML, now I just use the same logic to write in js file. But it fails. My code always puts all the data in one table.
Which part do I miss it? I scratch my head for a long time and can not fix it.

**test.js**

```
function createTable() {
        $.ajax({
                url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/test2",
                type: "GET",
                success: function (result) {
                    var mybody = document.getElementById("myDynamicTable");
                    var customer_status = (result);
                    var customers = JSON.parse(customer_status.Customer);
                    var carts = JSON.parse(customer_status.Cart);
                    var goods = JSON.parse(customer_status.Good);
                    for (var p in customers){
                        for (var c in carts){
                            if(customers[p].pk == carts[c].fields.customer){
                                for (var g in goods){
                                    if (carts[c].pk == goods[g].fields.cart){
                                        var tr2 = document.createElement('TR');
                                        tr2.className="trClass";
                                        var td1 = document.createElement('TD');
                                        var td2 = document.createElement('TD');
                                        var td3 = document.createElement('TD');
                                        var td4 = document.createElement('TD');
                                        td1.appendChild(document.createTextNode(goods[g].fields.name));
                                        td2.appendChild(document.createTextNode(goods[g].fields.count));
                                        td3.appendChild(document.createTextNode(goods[g].fields.price));
                                        td4.appendChild(document.createTextNode(goods[g].fields.count*goods[g].fields.price));
                                        tr2.appendChild(td1);
                                        tr2.appendChild(td2);
                                        tr2.appendChild(td3);
                                        tr2.appendChild(td4);
                                        mybody.appendChild(tr2);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
            $(".trClass").remove();
}
```

for example,
I use the admin site to add two cokes to the second customer, but it still displays under the fisrt customer.

[image: pic1]

please help! thank you.

**Update:** 
in my html, there is already a loop to create columns.

**test.html**

```
<div class="container custom-container-width" style="text-align=center;">
    <div class="grid-container" id="grid-container1">
        {% for customer in Customer %}
        <div class="gap-buffer " style="border:white;height:500px;">
            <div class="profilesize">
                <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}/{{customer.uuid}}/{{customer.uuid}}.jpeg" width=192 height=108>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="container ">
                <div class="table-responsive " >
                    <div class="table-shape ">
                        <table class = "table-shape">
                            <thead class="thead-dark">
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Product</th>
                                    <th>Count</th>
                                    <th>Price</th>
                                    <th>Subtotal</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody id="myDynamicTable" class="table-shape">
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <P><strong>Total:</strong></P>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

Comment: There is no code there that has any logic for putting content in *separate* tables. You only work with one table, `mybody`. There is no trace of another table in your code.

Comment: Hi, sorry, I should put my html code as well. in my html, there is a for-loop to create container columns. so It should be many tables. Am I right?

Comment: HTML is not a programming language: it has no loops. You probably refer to the `{% %}` tags, which are not HTML. Please tag your question with the system you use for that (templating) system

Comment: As you repeat the HTML generation of a table, you should not use `id=myDynamicTable`, because an `id` must be unique in valid HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the same `id` attribute value in a loop: that produces invalid HTML: an id should be unique. So just drop that `id` attribute. Use a specific class in the `class` attribute instead. Change this:

```
<tbody id="myDynamicTable" class="table-shape">
```

to this:

```
<tbody class="myDynamicTable table-shape">
```

In your JavaScript, change this:

```
var mybody = document.getElementById("myDynamicTable");
var customer_status = (result);
var customers = JSON.parse(customer_status.Customer);
var carts = JSON.parse(customer_status.Cart);
var goods = JSON.parse(customer_status.Good);
for (var p in customers){
    for (var c in carts){
```

to this:

```
var mytables = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".myDynamicTable")); // <---
var customer_status = (result);
var customers = JSON.parse(customer_status.Customer);
var carts = JSON.parse(customer_status.Cart);
var goods = JSON.parse(customer_status.Good);
for (var p in customers){
    var mybody = mytables.shift(); // <---
    for (var c in carts){
```

Comment: thanks a lot! It works!!!  I will be careful to post a question next time. really thank you!